# trigger to update custom object from Campaign Member object

Tags: apex, trigger

I am working on one trigger which will fire on "Staging_Event_Attendee__c" object after insert, after inserting the trigger need to match the Name field of Staging_Event_Attendee__c object with Id of CampaignMember object then update few fields on Staging_Event_Attendee__c from CampaignMember object.

I tried the below trigger but its now working properly, can anyone help me out in this issue here.

```
trigger StagingEventDetails on Staging_Event_Attendee__c (before insert) {
List<Staging_Event_Attendee__c> stagelist = new List<Staging_Event_Attendee__c>();
List<String> listname = new List<String>();
for(Staging_Event_Attendee__c sea : trigger.new){
    if(sea.Name != null){
        listname.add(sea.Name);
    }
}
List<CampaignMember> Campaign = [SELECT Id, ContactId,CampaignId From CampaignMember WHERE Id = : listname];
for( Staging_Event_Attendee__c c : Stagelist){
    c.Campaign_ID__c = Campaign[0].Id;
    c.Attendant__c = Campaign[0].ContactId;
    stagelist.add(c);
}
Update stagelist;
}
```

Comment: Is Name 15/18 digit alphanumeric Id?

Comment: Hello Pranay, its an 18 Digit Id

Comment: Its should be before insert instead of after insert, as in after insert the DML has already happened. Also you have SOQL inside for loop which should be removed. Setting value should happen in before trigger

Comment: @PranayJaiswal, I updated my code in question but still its not working, can you please review it once

Comment: are you getting any exception? and you should not hard code the index  [0] as your code will break if more than 1 `Staging_Event_Attendee__c` is instered via Dataloader or Bulk load

Comment: I am not getting any exception here,I think it will be bulk, actually I will be inserting Name field from a visualforce page

Comment: Your `Stagelist` is empty, and even if you iterate over it, and update it wont do a thing. Also as its before Insert, you dont have to use Update statement as it will alter values before inserting into database

Comment: This would be great starting point in understanding Apex Triggers. https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/apex_triggers/apex_triggers_intro

Answer (score 2):

You're using empty list 'stagelist' for the iteration at line no.10

```
 for( Staging_Event_Attendee__c c : Stagelist){
    //your logic to assign 
 }
```

Just replace the StageList with Trigger.New in the for loop, which will iterate the current records

```
for( Staging_Event_Attendee__c c : Trigger.New){
   //your logic to assign
}
```

Make sure the name one of a Staging_Event_Attendee__c record should be the campaign Id.

Since Name is a standard field(which is required), so no need to use the if condition. Remove the below conditon

`if(sea.Name != null)`

DML operations are not applicable on in before insert event on the same object. The original object has not been created; nothing can reference it, so nothing can update it.

Refer below code:

```
trigger StagingEventDetails on Staging_Event_Attendee__c (before insert) {
List<Staging_Event_Attendee__c> updateList = new List<Staging_Event_Attendee__c>();
List<String> namesList = new List<String>();
for(Staging_Event_Attendee__c sea : trigger.new){
        namesList.add(sea.Name);
}
Map<Id, CampaignMember> campaignMemberMap = new Map<Id, CampaignMember>([SELECT Id, ContactId FROM CampaignMember WHERE Id = : namesList]);
for( Staging_Event_Attendee__c c : trigger.new){
    c.Campaign_ID__c = campaignMemberMap.get(c.Name).Id;
    c.Attendant__c = campaignMemberMap.get(c.Name).ContactId;
}
```

}

Check more about trigger context variable considerations here https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_triggers_context_variables_considerations.htm

Comment: Hardcoded index?[0] ?

Comment: Updated the code @PranayJaiswal